# Remove duplicates from an already aggregated LISTAGG using LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, listagg, oracle19c

I have below two tables

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ONE  
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE_TWO
```

Result

```
ID|PRODUCTS   |TOTAL_AMOUNT|
--|-----------|------------|
 1|TABLE|CHAIR|           8|
 1|TABLE|TV   |          12|
 2|CUP        |          13|
 2|PLATE      |          14|
```

Now i want to do a `listagg` and as well remove duplicates on oracle 19c, therefore i use below query

```
SELECT ID, listagg(DISTINCT PRODUCTS, '|') within group (order by PRODUCTS)  PRODUCTS, SUM(AMOUNT) FROM (    
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ONE  
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE_TWO
) GROUP BY ID
```

**Result i get is**

```
ID|PRODUCTS            |SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT)|
--|--------------------|-----------------|
 1|TABLE|CHAIR|TABLE|TV|               20|
 2|CUP|PLATE           |               27|
```

**Result that i want is**

```
ID|PRODUCTS            |SUM(TOTAL_AMOUNT)|
--|--------------------|-----------------|
 1|TABLE|CHAIR|TV      |               20|
 2|CUP|PLATE           |               27|
```

Test data in [db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3ccc30c81c81dcb6d8f211b5740d76f9) Although it is `oracle18c`, doesn't support distinct in listagg i am using `oracle 19c`

Comment: The problem is `'TABLE|CHAIR'` is one string and `'TABLE|TV'` another string altogether. If you are interested in the separate parts then store them separately. I.e. you need child tables holding the single products.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner now that is why i have asked the question, how do i remove the duplicates after i have merged the two.

Comment: I am saying you are not using your DBMS properly. Build a *relational* database. That means no concatenated strings like `'TABLE|CHAIR'`. Let's say your tables are orders. Then you'd want another table for the products and a third table linking products and orders.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i get you. although, i am aggregating reports based on a given usecase to be used for marketing by 3rd party client. we already have that relational db. table_one is day one report and i would want to merge between dates easily using just a simple select query.

Comment: Okay. The tables represent aggregation results, thus containing concatenated strings. Now you want to build upon this and de-concatenate the strings again. It may be possible to detect and remove duplicates in a concatenated string with `REGEXP_REPLACE`, but I guess I'd rather write a PL/SQL function that splits the string and concatenates its distinct parts then.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner drop the answer, i try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below to unlistagg and remove the duplicate and then listagg again.**[The DB Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0142e2148350a425974f2dba3b345d5a)**

```
            WITH data
         AS (SELECT id,
                    Listagg(products, '|')
                      within GROUP (ORDER BY products) PRODUCTS,
                    SUM(amount)                        SUM_AMT
             FROM   (SELECT *
                     FROM   table_one
                     UNION
                     SELECT *
                     FROM   table_two)
             GROUP  BY id),
         d2
         AS (SELECT DISTINCT id,
                             Regexp_substr(products, '[^|]+', 1, column_value) AS
                             products,
                             sum_amt
             FROM   data
                    cross join TABLE(Cast(MULTISET (SELECT LEVEL
                                              FROM   dual
                                              CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                              Regexp_count(products,
                                              '[^|]+'))
                                                       AS
    sys.ODCINUMBERLIST)))
    SELECT id,
           Listagg(products, '|')
             within GROUP (ORDER BY id) PRODUCTS,
           sum_amt
    FROM   d2
    GROUP  BY id,
              sum_amt;
```